# Exclude Rest Controller from Production Profile and Testing Profile Exclusion

Tags: java, spring

My application has a RestController for User administration; this has been very helpful in pre-production. I want to avoid allowing spring to wire the `UserController` into the application when the production profile is active.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/user")
public class UserController {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController .class);
```

My Test Class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@ActiveProfiles(value = {SPRING_PROFILE_TEST})
public class UserControllerTest {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using a profile, I was able to restrict the Controller Component to only the Test and Development.

```
@Profile({SPRING_PROFILE_TEST, SPRING_PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT})
public class UserController {
```

In my test class, I've added the following code to ensure the `UserController` is still being wired correctly

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@ActiveProfiles(value = {SPRING_PROFILE_TEST})
public class UserControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private UserController UserController; //confirm controller can be autowired
```

[Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html)